# Combobox / Dropdown box not updating after its data was updated

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, ajax, model-view-controller

A long explanation but I believe this is a pretty simple question. I think I'm missing something here.

After selecting a user role from a dropdown menu I'm loading a partial view with users for that role into a DIV with ajax:

```
        $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        data: { id: roleId},
        url: '@Url.Action("Manage","User")',
        success: function (data) {
            $("#user-manage").html(data);
        }
    });
```

Now, on the page I have a combobox with the list of users and a Delete button. 
I highlight a user, press the Delete button and user gets deleted.

Great! It works ,however my problem is that the deleted user doesn't disappear from the Combobox list until the page is refreshed. And I can't refresh the page because that'd mean that web site user would have to start over with selecting the Role.

So, the question is how can I make the user disappear on the combobox as soon as I hit that delete button ?

Right now when the delete button is pressed the selected UserId is passed the following ajax call that deletes a selected user and returns the updated JSON user list:

```
    function removeUser() {
    var selectedUser = $("#user-combo").find(":selected").val(); //grab selected user
    var selectedForRole = $("#role-id").val(); //hidden field to store selected role

    $.ajax({
        url:"/User/Delete", //Delete selected user and return updated Json list
        data: { id: selectedUser , roleId: selectedForRole },
        type: 'post',
        success: function (data) {
            var userList = $("#user-combo");
            var listContent;

            $.each(data, function (index, item) {
                listContent += "<option value='" + item.Id + "'>" + item.Name + "</option>";
            });

            userList.html(listContent);
        }
    });
}
```

Functionally this works. The user gets deleted but I don't see it reflected on the $("#user-combo") box until I refresh the screen.

location.reload(); doesn't work for me as I don't want the web site user to go through selecting a role to see the updated list of users.

How can I make this interactive and users disappear when I delete them  and appear when add them later on ?

Thank you in advance.

Edit.
Json object returned to the combobox:

```
return Json(roleUsers.Select(x => new
            {
                Id = x.Id,
                Name = x.Name
            }));
```

Comment: Do you ever remove the option from the combobox in your code?

Comment: Well the collection I'm returning to the combobox has that record removed so I assume doing .html([updated collection]) should replace comobox elements with updated data ? Am I wrong ?

Comment: It would, assuming the data is sent correctly from the server. Are you return the data as a json encoded object?

Comment: yeah, I return Json encoded anonnymouse type. See modified OP at the bottom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is as simple as this:

```
$("#comboBox option[value='USER-NAME']").remove();
```

Put this in your `removeUser()`. function.

In fact the function must not olny remve the user from the remote list, but also from the DOM.
Hpe this help.

Comment: SO there is no way to really bind the combobox to have it updated as the returns JSON collection changes ? I have to remove Combobox elements on the client side manually with [COmbobox].remove() ?

Comment: Yes of course there is a way, but you should be using some framework like backbone.js (there are others but this is really cutting edge). Usually with such javascript framework based on the MVC (model, view, controller) model, you have a collection of elements. When you remove an element from a collection it is automatically refreshed and re-rendered CLIENT SIDE (without reloading the page). If you want to know more I suggest to start from this link http://backbonetutorials.com/

Answer (score 0):

Check your callback function. Logic seems to be OK. I have just tested and replacing select's html will remove old items and add new ones. Here's a [fiddle for that](http://jsfiddle.net/miroslav/qJULT/2/).

Add several console.log() calls in your success callback function. console.log(data); console.log(userList); console.log(listContent) and see if they contain the correct data... or whether they get executed at all.

For another possible cause check your roleUsers list on the server. It maybe contains the deleted user - i.e. if you pull it out from the cache and not from the database, or you do delete after the list load.